# Xamarin UWP app size is too big? how to reduce?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have built a xamarin forms app and android size 17mb using proguard, full linking. 
However UWP size is 76 mb. I am already using configuration as in the screenshot below.
I am support x86, x64 and arm architectures on both platforms. in android i create separate packages per abi. thats why 17mb is each abi size. but I couldnt find a similar option in UWP. it is size of bundle.
is there a way to provide 3 installers? Beside that why is the size too large and how can i optimize it further?

PS; on native side, i dont have much code. 95 of the code is in shared project even images are embedded in shared project. plus, android has more images.

[image]

EDIT: I tried the option "include full PDB files" by unchecking but it didnt help me at all. it only reduced 2 mb size.

[image]

Comment: Actually it is full package size , when you place your package on store respective device download required architecture file only , i have also large package but when user download it in mobile, download size is different and if pc user download app , download size will be diffrent

Comment: @ShubhamSahu nice to know this. do pc users get full size? or based on their pc's architecture?

Comment: According to architecture x86,x64, ARM (mobile and other arm device),

Comment: One more tip also view your total assets or images if used optimize it if you can but this will not make any huge difference

Comment: @ShubhamSahu it looks your Statement is not correct for Desktops at least. I dont own a phone right now but ir i download and install on a Desktop, it downloads full size