# How Do I Reduce Size of UWP App (Can I Compress HD Images?)

Tags: image, uwp, compression, size

My UWP app for Windows 10, which is in development at the moment and has about 400 - 500 HD images, takes up a whopping 1.7 GB of hard drive space. File Explorer claims that the images take up about 1.68 GB while the code is the other 0.02 GB...

When all is said and done, the app needs to have a couple thousand HD images. Clearly this will be unsustainable as the size of the app will be nearly 10 GB, or possibly even larger.

Is there a way to compress these images within the app?

This is unrelated to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840835/xamarin-uwp-app-size-is-too-big-how-to-reduce). I am not using Xamarin. Also I tested downloading a release build from the Store to confirm--and it does in fact say it is 1.7 GB in size.

Comment: What format are the images in? Do you need them all in the main package, or can some of them be in resource packages (eg for different languages or different display scale factors?)

Comment: They are JPG, and yes they are all needed at runtime regardless of language and resolution.

Comment: OK, JPG is already a compressed format so you typically can't compress further (MSIX is in fact a compressed ZIP archive with extra metadata). Have you tried regenerating them at a lower quality or slightly smaller size?

Comment: I thought the images were at 1080 HD resolution, but it turns out they are at 4K which is unnecessary for my purposes. I will downscale them. That should help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images used in the application are actually application resources.

When the application is packaged, this part of the resource will not be specially processed. You can only compress the image before packaging, or consider extracting the image resource to allow the user to Download and import image resources after installing the application.

Just like some online games, after downloading the game body, they will download additional data packets the first time they run. This part of the resource is not hosted by the store, but is deposited by the developer.